# How to retrieve all instances of an attribute from an xml

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a piece of code below where it looks for an attribute known as `'ExtranetContract'`within the xml and performs an assertion to check that the attribute does exist and that its value equals '`true'`.

```
def DailyContracts = xml.'soap:Body'
                .TestResponse
                .TestContractType
                .DailyContracts

def ContractType = DailyContracts.findAll { it.@Type == "C"}

def ExtranetContract = ContractType.DailyContract[0].@ExtranetContract

assert ExtranetContract.size() > 0 && ExtranetContract.every { it == 'true' }
```

Notice the line: `def ExtranetContract = ContractType.DailyContract[0].@ExtranetContract`. The `[0]` represents the first instance of `DailyContract`(where the contact type equals `'C'`.

I am not sure if it will work if I have two or more extranet contracts under contract type `'C'` (I have't got an example to test myself but I have created a dummy xml to show an example on where the above line of code may not work effectively in checking all extranet contracts attributes

```
<Contracts>
 <DailyContracts Type="S">
    <DailyContract Type="TEST" Code="xxx">
       <Name>Extranet</Name>
    </DailyContract>
    </DailyContracts>
 <DailyContracts Type="C">
  <DailyContract Type="TEST" Code="xxx" ExtranetContract="true">
    <Name>Test Hotel 1</Name>
  </DailyContract>
    <DailyContract Type="TEST" Code="xxx" ExtranetContract="true">
    <Name>Test Hotel 2</Name>
  </DailyContract>
 </DailyContracts>
</Contracts>
```

My question is simply how can I replace the `[0]` so that it checks all extranet contracts? I tried replacing `[0]` with `.findAll` and `'collect'` but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line:

```
def ExtranetContract = ContractType.DailyContract[0].@ExtranetContract
```

gives you an instance of [FilteredNodeChildren](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/FilteredNodeChildren.html). Since this class is an instance of `Iterable` you can use [spread](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator) operator:

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper

def input = '''<Contracts>
 <DailyContracts Type="S">
    <DailyContract Type="FIT" Code="xxx" Start="2017-08-15" Days="7">
       <Name>Extranet</Name>
    </DailyContract>
    </DailyContracts>
 <DailyContracts Type="C">
  <DailyContract Type="FIT" Code="xxx" Start="2017-08-15" Days="7" ExtranetContract="true">
    <Name>Melia Costa Del Sol Extranet</Name>
  </DailyContract>
    <DailyContract Type="FIT" Code="xxx" Start="2017-08-15" Days="7" ExtranetContract="true">
    <Name>Melia Costa Del Sol Extranet 2</Name>
  </DailyContract>
 </DailyContracts>
</Contracts>'''

def slurped = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input)

def ContractType = slurped.DailyContracts.findAll { it.@Type == "C"}

def ExtranetContract = ContractType.DailyContract*.@ExtranetContract

assert ExtranetContract.size() == 2 && ExtranetContract.every { it == 'true' }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it as below:

```
//Pass the response as String to parseText method
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
//Get the Daily Contracts of type C
def contracts = xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'DailyContracts' && it.@Type == 'C'}
//Get the ExtranetContract values
def eCon = contracts.DailyContract*.@ExtranetContract
assert eCon instanceof List
assert !(false in eCon)
```

You can try it quickly online <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5186581635792896)</kbd>